# Getting systemNullReference excepetion when changing menu item's title - Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, menu

I am developing an android app using c#, my problem is when I am changing the menu item's title outside of the button event, in the `Oncreate` method, I am getting a `SystemNullReference excepetion` but I am able to do it inside the button click event without getting an excepetion. What I want to do is to change the item's title inside the `Oncreate method` so that directly when the app starts, the items title should be changed. What I have so far:

```
private IMenu menu;
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu, menu);
        return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            IMenuItem about = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.About); // Everything is working on the button click
            about.SetTitle("About);
         };
        if (selected == "English") // selected is a string value saved in Shared Preference
        {
            IMenuItem about = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.About); // here where I am getting the SystemNullReference excepetion
            about.SetTitle("About);
         }
      }
```

Why I am having this exception and how to solve this ?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Don't know enough about android, but I guess `OnCreateOptionsMenu` is called _after_ `OnCreate`, so in `OnCreate`, `menu` is still `null`. Can you try to change the title in `OnCreateOptionsMenu` instead of in `OnCreate`? It works in the button handler because this is only executed when the button is clicked, not directly when executing `OnCreate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this part of code:

```
 if (selected == "English") // selected is a string value saved in Shared Preference
    {
        IMenuItem about = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.About); // here where I am getting the SystemNullReference excepetion
        about.SetTitle("About);
     }
```

into the end of `OnCreateOptionsMenu` before `return` statement.

You should do it because you init the `private IMenu menu;` value in the `OnCreateOptionsMenu`, which is called **after** `OnCreate()`, and you are using the `private IMenu menu;` in `OnCreate`, while it was not initialized so far.